# Unable to connect to wired network with 802.1x security and (PEAP authentication)

Tags: networking, network-manager, 21.10

I am trying to connect to my college LAN and have done everything I was asked to do, but am unable to connect.

The setup:

authentication: PEAP

inner authentication: MSCHAPv2

(and credentials)

Here's what I have tried as of now

1. I have tried using the GUI but the error wasn't very insightful
2. I tried connecting using `nmcli`

`nmcli con up iiithauthcert --ask` where `iiithauthcert` is the name I have given to the profile.

I ran the command on a terminal window and ran `journalctl -f -t NetworkManager` on another

The logs are as follows

```
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1160] device (enp4s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1184] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'iiithauthcert' (0ae6a421-26cd-4303-a902-c59d45f17f7b)
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1207] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1215] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1223] device (enp4s0): Activation: (ethernet) connection 'iiithauthcert' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1224] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240501.1229] device (enp4s0): Activation: (ethernet) asking for new secrets
Dec 11 22:05:01 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <warn>  [1639240501.1360] dispatcher: (28) /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with status 2.
Dec 11 22:05:36 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240536.0709] device (enp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:36 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240536.0717] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:36 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240536.0727] device (enp4s0): Activation: (ethernet) connection 'iiithauthcert' requires no security. No secrets needed.
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <error> [1639240539.0751] device (enp4s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Failed to D-Bus activate wpa_supplicant service
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0752] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'supplicant-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <warn>  [1639240539.0762] device (enp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'iiithauthcert'
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0767] device (enp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0793] policy: auto-activating connection 'iiithauthcert' (0ae6a421-26cd-4303-a902-c59d45f17f7b)
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0806] device (enp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'iiithauthcert' (0ae6a421-26cd-4303-a902-c59d45f17f7b)
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0807] device (enp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0810] device (enp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0813] device (enp4s0): Activation: (ethernet) connection 'iiithauthcert' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0813] device (enp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 11 22:05:39 lap-G3-3500 NetworkManager[992]: <info>  [1639240539.0815] device (enp4s0): Activation: (ethernet) asking for new secrets
```

Please note that I am sure my credentials are being input correctly because I am dual booting with windows 10 and am able to successfully able to connect to the LAN there (with those credentials)

Please let me know if there is some other information I should provide for better insight into my issue.

The Ubuntu system I am running is 21.10

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you even read the log? Look for "`failed`", and find out why the listed script exited with an error status of 2.

Comment: @waltinator I did read the error log and the script happened to be a NetworkManager script. I have looked up about that specific error line but to no avail. 

Could you suggest a way I could get more information on why that script fails?